# Populate dataframe with variable value pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I really hope you can help.

I am working on the below, which finds the closest schools to a particular property.

Everything is working fine, except the final step. Where I define the field 'Primary' in the raw_data dataframe, it always returns NaN, but, if I step through, the variable Primary_Name does get populated.

Any idea why this might be?

```
for index, row in raw_data.iterrows():  
    start = (row['lat'], row['long'])

    for index, row in schools.iterrows():
        schoolloc = (row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])
        schools.loc[index,'distance'] = geopy.distance.geodesic(start, schoolloc).km

    schools.dropna()
    primary = schools.where(schools['PhaseOfEducation (name)'] == 'Primary')
    Nearest_Primary = primary[primary['distance'] == min(primary['distance'])]
    Primary_Name = Nearest_Primary.iloc[0]['EstablishmentName']
    raw_data.loc[index,'primary'] = Primary_Name
```

Comment: don't use the same variables names `index`  and `row` for both loops, maybe it will help as you try to access a row in `raw_data` with `index` which is at this moment the last index of `schools` and this at each loop over `raw_data`

Comment: You are the man! Thanks Ben. I feel stupid now